# autocomplete typehead not working

Tags: php, typehead

typehead suggestions not working in real hosting but in localhost it work perfectly, what's the reason it is not working in real host.

here is my code

html code

```
<form method="POST" action="result.php">
                                    <input type="text" name="city" class="city form-control" Placeholder="Enter Your Area!">
                                    <input type="submit" name="submit" role="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" style="margin-top:-11px;background-color:#FFA500;">    
                                </form>
```

javascript code

```
<script src="js/typeahead.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script>
        $(document).ready(function() {

            $('input.city').typeahead({
                name: 'city',
                remote: 'search.php?query=%QUERY'

            });

        })
    </script>
```

PHP code(search.php)

```
<?php

//CREDENTIALS FOR DB
define ('DBSERVER', 'localhost');
define ('DBUSER', 'root');
define ('DBPASS','');
define ('DBNAME','hotel');

//LET'S INITIATE CONNECT TO DB
$connection = mysql_connect(DBSERVER, DBUSER, DBPASS) or die("Can't connect to server. Please check credentials and try again");
$result = mysql_select_db(DBNAME) or die("Can't select database. Please check DB name and try again");

//CREATE QUERY TO DB AND PUT RECEIVED DATA INTO ASSOCIATIVE ARRAY
if (isset($_REQUEST['query'])) {
    $query = $_REQUEST['query'];
    $sql = mysql_query ("SELECT locations, loc_id FROM delhi WHERE locations LIKE '%{$query}%' OR loc_id LIKE '%{$query}%'");
    $array = array();
    while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
        $array[] = array (
            'label' => $row['locations'].', '.$row['loc_id'],
            'value' => $row['locations'],
        );
    }
    //RETURN JSON ARRAY
    echo json_encode ($array);
}

?>
```

here is the screenshot for my localhost page:
[image]
and you can check live action here -> hostelhome.co

Comment: Stop using `mysql_*` functions. They are deprecated already. Use MySQLi / PDO instead. Also, your codes are vulnerable to SQL Injection, always clean up the variables from GET / POST / REQUEST before you use it in your SQL.

Comment: `mysql_connect` Ouch. `mysql_*` functions are deprecated, check your PHP versions